# symfony2 after cache clear get blank page

Tags: symfony, caching

I thought I solved a permissions issue by removing cached files, then giving 777 permissions, it works and shows the page for my site with the htaccess set to remove /web/app_dev.php.  But if do  php app/console cache:clear --env=prod it goes back to a blank page again and the permission go back to 755 , how do I change permission on the cache:clear thanks ?

```
 rm -rf app/cache/*
 rm -rf app/logs/*

 chmod 777 -R app/cache 
 chmod 777 -R app/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the permissions like it says here in the documentation, using ACL, or with setfacl

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup